# Combobox style windows metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a xaml/c# metro style app in windows 8. I'd like to emulate the Microsoft Calendar app comboBox Style (In the event details page). I mean, having that behavior of coloured box and border after selection. How can I do it using visual states?

Comment: check out http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard control for this, you have to create your own / extend the standard combobox

Comment: I know there's no standard control. My question was about achieving that effect. I'm able to achieve something similar by using GotFocus and LostFocus events in c#, but I'd like to modify the combobox template using VisualStates. How can I do it? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<Combobox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/> <!--leave the unfocused state empty if the control already looks "unfocused" -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.2" Duration="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Border x:Name="background" Background="Red" Opacity="0" />
        <!--other stuff-->
    </ControlTemplate>
</Combobox.Template>
```

The Combobox control automatically switches it's built-in states according to mouse/keyboard input like focused, pressed, mouse over etc. By switching a state the storyboard that was defined for the current state will be reversed and the storyboard that you have defined for the new state will be applied. You can review the available states here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx

(Using code-behind you can also implement your own states based on events and such, but this should be rarely needed.)